# How does Scapy disable the FCS?

Tags: frame, scapy, checksum, crc

I'm trying to send an Ethernet frame with no / corrupt FCS (to test some custom hardware which has a specific error counter for this).

I've found Scapy, which does this very simply.

What I want to do is replicate this in my own app, which is written in C# running on Windows.  I already generate raw Ethernet frames which I send using PCAP.NET, but I haven't found any way of disabling FCS.

So my original question is: how does Scapy disasble the FCS?  If someone can point me to the source code (I had a look for FCS and SO_NOFCS but didn't find anything useful) or explain conceptually.

This may lead to a follow-up question: how do I do this in C# on Win 10?  (some vague hints out there about SO_NOFCS but I can't find evidence that Windows supports this).

I was trying to understand, at a source code or conceptual level, how Scapy suppresses addition of the FCS.